# how to display nslog output contents on Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: iphone

I just upgrade to Xcode 4.3.1

For the old version of Xcode, it is easy to display nslog contents

but Xcode it display

[image]

I prefer the text output! Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View - Debug Aera - Activate Console，or `Command+Shift+C`.